# Install4j: Various icon sizes?

Tags: windows, install4j, shortcut-file

I've created a 256 x 256 @ 96DPI PNG and ICO. I've set them accordingly in Install4j and it comes out great when I build the installer. It resizes to 256x256 on Windows but after you install it, the console application does not retain the original 256x256 image. Thus, the image remains IIRC at 64x64 and no larger.

We would like to ensure that our application supports the maximum icon size on Windows/Mac at 256x256.

I'll keep tinkering with it to ensure it's not a problem on my end but I'm having a feeling that install4j does not build the appropriate image sizes for the actual executable / console.

Thank you,

Chris

---

**Update**

So I've determined that the actually executable itself retains the icon size at 256x256. When you create a shortcut (which is where I was noticing this) it does not resize to 256x256. This is something with Windows. Maybe shortcuts expect a variety of sizes embedded into the executable? Anyone?